# Solving a linear congruence system

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

How can this linear congruence system be solved by using Chinese remainder theorem?

\begin{align}
12x&\equiv -7 \pmod {13}\\
4x&\equiv 7 \pmod {9}\\
2x&\equiv -3 \pmod {11}
\end{align}

As far as I understand, we have to create some M numbers as it follows:
\begin{align}
M = 13 * 9 * 11 = 1287\\
M_1 = 9 * 11 = 99\\
M_2 = 13 * 11 = 143\\
M_3 = 13 * 9 = 117
\end{align}

But from here forward it becomes confusing for me. What should be done next?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Solve the first congruence:

$$12x \equiv -7 \pmod{13} \implies x \equiv 7 \pmod{13}$$

So now we know $x = 13t+7$ for some integer $t$.

Substitute into the second congruence:
$$
4(13t+7)\equiv 7\pmod 9
$$
Solve this and you'll find that $t\equiv c \pmod 9$ for some constant $c$.  Then you'll know that $t = 9s +c$ for some integer $s$.  Substitute this into the expression for $x$ above, and you'll have $x=9\cdot 13s + k$ for some integer $k$.  Substitute this into the third congruence and solve for $s$ modulo 11. Finally, you'll get an expression for $x$ modulo $13 \cdot 9 \cdot 11$

Answer (score 0):

You can start by simplifying each of the given equations into the form $x\equiv k_i \bmod m_i$.

For example, $4x \equiv 7 \equiv 16 \implies x\equiv 4 \bmod 9$

Then the [generalized solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Existence_(direct_construction)) to the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) becomes more accessible.

However it's often at least as efficient to construct the answer by combining $2$ modulus equations at a time to make a resulting single equation, especially if some of the $k_i$ turn out to be the same (as here).

Answer (score 0):

Note that CRT guarantees that an unique solution exist mod $9\cdot 11 \cdot 13$ since those are relatively primes but doesn’t give any particular method to solve the problem others that those used for the proof that you can find [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem.).

To find the solution here we can proceed as follow

- $12x \equiv -7 \iff x\equiv 7 \pmod {13}$
- $4x\equiv 7 \iff x\equiv 4 \pmod {9}$
- $2x\equiv -3 \iff x\equiv 4 \pmod {11}$

this is the standard form for the system , then

- $x\equiv 7 \pmod {13}\implies x=7+13k$
- $x\equiv 4\implies 7+4k\equiv 4\implies 4k\equiv 6 \implies k\equiv 6  \pmod {9}\implies x=7+13(6+9h)=85+9\cdot13h$
- $x\equiv 4 \implies 8+7h\equiv4 \implies h\equiv 1 \pmod {11} \implies x=85+9\cdot13(1+11s)=202+9\cdot11\cdot 13s$

that is $$x=202 \pmod{9\cdot11\cdot 13}$$